# Exponential map of Lie brakets

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Let $G$ be a compact matrix Lie group and $(\mathfrak{g},[,])$ its Lie algebra. For $x$, $x'$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{g}$, $[x,x']=xx'-x'x$. My question is if there exists a relation between exp$(t[x,x'])$ and exp$(tx)$, exp$(tx')$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula?

Comment: No, what is it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula.  It will tell you something like $\exp(tx) \exp(tx') \exp(-tx) \exp(-tx') = \exp(t^2[x, x'] + O(t^3))$.  Is that the kind of statement you want?

Comment: It looks good. Thanks